# How do I use WebStorm with typescript and Meteor 1.3

Tags: meteor, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2016.1 and Meteor 1.3 and typescript files.  When I use 'import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor'I get the error 'import Error Cannot find module 'meteor/meteor'

I have run 'typings install meteor --save --ambient' and the packages seem to be inplace in the typings directory...

Comment: Are you inside the `meteor create appname` folder?

Comment: Yes.  The top folder of me webstorm project was created by 'meteor create ...'

Answer (score -1):

This issue was mostly fixed with a new release of WebStorm. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21183

So, make sure you have WebStorm 2016.1.2, Build #WS-145.971 or later installed.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12359852)

Comment: Essential parts added. Answer is now standalone.